# Recursive regex match

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

I use `/<?=>|[^\s\w]|\w+/g` to match

- <=>
- =>
- words/letters

but I also want to match `K(a,...)` where `a` can be any word/letter and `...` can be anything also matched in this final regex. So it actually has to be recursive.

So the new regex should match

- <=>
- =>
- words/letters
- K(a,...)

where `...` matches

- <=>
- =>
- words/letters
- K(a,...)

and so on...

I am not sure if this is possible.

I am not sure if it might be easier to create a function that walks through each character in a string recursively, which is something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: Javascript regex doesn't support recursive pattern, better to write a parser as you're suggesting.

Comment: You can try using http://xregexp.com/ library.

Comment: @Karpak Why would xregexp help?

Comment: This is RegExp extension library. the function XRegExp.matchRecursive in this library helps to do the recursive RegExp matches.

Comment: @Jamgreen. Please provide some example with at least with 3 levels of recursive example string along with the output that you want. JS doesn't support recursive RegEx directly, However, it can be done using other libraries. If you provide example, then only SO should be able to suggest you something.

Comment: It should match with an infinite number of recursions, e.g. `K(a,K(b,K(c,p => q)))` etc.

Comment: Thx and I understand about recursive infinite times. But Im still not clear about whats the output you are expecting if the is the your string. Are you expexting just a true/false or list of matches?

Comment: I expect a list of all the matches.. So in a input `ps<=>q=>pb=>K(ab,K(b,K(c,p => q)))`, I expect an array `['ps', '<=>', 'q', '=>', 'pb', '=>', 'K(ab,K(b,K(c,p => q)))']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regexp to match. Based on the example that you gave the below would work.

```
/(K\(.+,(.+)\)|<?=>)|\w+\1/g
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex used in the javascript below doesn't use recursion.
Since that's not available in standard javascript regex.

It takes advantage of the fact that all the `)` are at the end.
As in the example string from the comments.

```js
var str = "ps<=>q=>pb=>K(ab,K(b,K(c,p => q)))  not)";

var re = /\w+(?:\([^()]+)+[)]+|<?=>|\w+(?=<?=>)/g;

var matchArray = [];
var m;

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
    matchArray.push(m[0]);
}

console.log(matchArray);
```